# How to get all entries of a map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how get all the entries of a map in javascript and execute a function for all of them (create a section in an HTML with template).

It would be the equivalent of a java code like that :

```
for(Entry e : Map.getAllEntries){
    function{}
}
```

Here the code before :

```js
var siteMap = new Map();

        var sample = new site("sample", "http://sample.com", "sample.png",
                             "Sample is sample that sample the sample",
                             "SAMPLE");
        siteMap.set(sample.name, sample);
```

Thanks in advance,
TBD

Comment: I've put a java code to explicit my question. Its is about javascript but even thanks :)

Comment: What map are you using in JS?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Examples)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I miss the function that was at the down of the doc page the code like that work fine...

```
var siteMap = new Map();

        var sample = new site("sample", "http://sample.com", "sample.png",
                             "Sample is sample that sample the sample",
                             "SAMPLE");
        siteMap.set(sample.name, sample);

siteMap.forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value.url);
});
```

TBD

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure js Map.forEach function (ES6):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

```
map.forEach(function(value, key, innerMap) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: I use nodeJS so its just JS ... :(

Comment: Ugh, why suggest a massive and nearly obsolete code library to do simple iteration?

Comment: Don't use jQuery if it isn't tagged.

Comment: Yop that's i've found ! :)

Comment: @doodlemeister sorry, it's true, that's too easy but a lot of times not very optimal. http://vanilla-js.com/